# Armeria grpc client: how can I set different retry behavior for different grpc methods

Tags: armeria

I am using Armeria grpc client as follows:

```
Clients.builder("gproto+http://....")
  .decorator(RetryingClient.newDecorator(retryRule, maxAttempts, perAttemptTimeout))
```

This enforces this retry behavior across all outgoing requests.

Is there a way to provide different retry parameters for each grpc method offered by the target service?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Haitham.
You already created the issue for that
https://github.com/line/armeria/issues/3128
Please keep an eye on it. :)